# Run Time Error #3

Tags: c++

I'm in an intro to C++ class and we're working with visual studio. Our assignment was to create a program that would calculate different things that the user could choose from by typing in the corresponding character. The activity was to show us how to use functions in our code. I've setup the first calculation but every time I run it I get a runtime error #3 and when I initialize circleArea in the main, circleArea is printed as whatever I initialized it to instead of the value returned by the areaCircle function. Thanks for heping me out and I'm sorry if this is very elementary of me.

---

```
/// Lab6Marcelino.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double pi = 3.14;

// Protoypes
void showMenu(char & c);
void getRadius(double & r, bool &nega);
bool isNegative(double val);
double areaCircle(double &r);

// Main
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char menuChoice;
    double radius;
    bool negative = true;
    double circleArea;

    showMenu(menuChoice);

    if (menuChoice = 'c')
    {
        getRadius(radius, negative);
        areaCircle(radius);

        cout << "The radius is " << radius << endl
            << "The area of the circle is: " << circleArea << endl;
    }



    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

//*************
// FUNCTIONS***
//*************

// Definition of function showMenu
// Shows Menu and asks for user choice.

void showMenu(char &menuChoice)
    {
        cout << "Enter C or c for the area of a Circle" << endl
        << "Enter T or t for the area of a Triangle" << endl
        << "Enter S or s for the area of a Sphere" << endl
        << "Enter P or p for the area of a triangular Prism" << endl
        << "Enter A or a for information about the author" << endl
        << "Enter Q or q to quit this program" << endl;
        cin >> menuChoice;
    }

// Definition of function getRadius
// Gets radius from user

void getRadius(double &r, bool &nega)
    {
        cout << "Enter the radius: ";
    cin >> r;
        isNegative(r);

        while (isNegative(r) == true)
        {
            cout << "Enter the radius: ";
            cin >> r;
            isNegative(r);
        }
    }

bool isNegative(double val)
    {
        if (val < 0)
            return true;

        if (val > 0)
            return false;
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }

double areaCircle(double &r)
{
    double circleArea;
    circleArea = pi * r * r;
    return circleArea;
}
```

Comment: `circleArea = areaCircle(radius);`

Comment: circleArea isn't initialize in main.

Comment: I have no idea what a "Run Time Error #3" is. You should start by stepping through the program and seeing what works and what does not work. This should also help you find the particular line causing the problem.

Comment: `if (menuChoice = 'c')` That isn't right. Use `==` to compare, not `=`

Comment: what @PaulMcKenzie pointed out is particularly bad, because it won't cause a compile error or an exception, but the behavior will not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`areaCircle(radius);` returns a value, but you're not assigning it to anything.  Then, when you try to use `circleArea` with cout, it hasn't been initialized, so that's probably where you're getting the runtime error.